# Embed a video player in C# Web App

Tags: c#, asp.net, video

I am trying to embed a video into my web app. It seems that there is a player there but it looks like I am missing something. Here is what's in the aspx file. It basically just displays a grey bar with a play button in it but it does not allow me play anything or show any video.

```
<video src="C:\PathToVideo\etc\video.mp4" controls autoplay>HTML5 Video example</video>
```

Comment: You need to host the video on the web server and provide a URL to the video that's accessible over the HTTP protocol. Not just provide a local physical path.

Comment: This is not true for IE, Chrome, Firefox all in most current version on Win10. It is absolutely fine to provide local paths for testing

Answer (score 0):

you code is basically fine, i can only imagine 2 reasons for you video not to play:

1) you browser does not support the codec or specifics of the container of your mp4 file

2) you need to escape the backslashes in your filepath, e.g. "C:\\PathToVideo\\etc\\video.mp4"

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I resolved this by doing what mason suggested. My thinking was in line with Harry's on the local path, but I guess that was incorrect. I changes the src to a URL on the server(localhost) and that was all that was needed. Video plays and displays normally. I guess we know now. Thanks, all!

Comment: Greaat! I am interested in your scenario, as i might hit it at some point in time. Could you maybe hint me on your OS and browser? Also, did you maybe install addtionaly codecs to your windows?

Comment: Windows 10 Pro, and I was testing in Chrome. No additional installs, however, I did go to IIS and verify that I had MIME types for .mp4 extensions. Sometimes that can cause a problem.